# Failed to inject value for parameter [IProductManager] of class, No bean of type exists

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

Dependency Injection issue with Micronaut. I am using Micronaut version 2.1.0 and keep facing the dependency injection issue.

```
{
  "message": "Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [IProductManager] of class: fete.bird.api.v1.controller.ProductController\n\nMessage: No bean of type [fete.bird.manager.IProductManager] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).\nPath Taken: new ProductController([IProductManager IProductManager])"
}
```

Interface

```
@Introspected
public interface IProductManager {
    List<ProductViewModel> findFreeText(String text);
}
```

Implementation

```
@Singleton
public class ProductManager implements IProductManager{
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductManager.class);
    public ProductManager(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductViewModel> findFreeText(String text) {
        LOG.info("Manager --> Finding all the products");
        final List<ProductViewModel> model = new ArrayList<>();
        
         return model;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller("/api/v1/product")
public class ProductController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);
    private final IProductManager iProductManager;

    public ProductController(IProductManager IProductManager) {
        this.iProductManager = IProductManager;
    }

    @Get(uri = "/{text}")
    List<ProductViewModel> freeTextSearch(String text) {
        LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
        return iProductManager.findFreeText(text);
    }
}
```

I am using Intellj IDE. If I delete the build folder and run the application all works fine, but while running the application multiple time keeps getting above error. Every time I need to delete the build folder to make it work

Comment: Do you know why `IProductManager` is marked with `@Introspected`?

Comment: I shouldn't mark that as a @Introspected, at the beginning I thought it might be due to bean creation. However, I removed it later

Comment: You have not indicated which build tool you are using.  Are you using Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are experiencing the bug described at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/4277.

If that is the case, you can make the problem go away by disabling incremental compilation as described in that bug report.  Note that doing a full clean build also may remedy the issue, but only until the next time the build triggers the same problem.

Comment: FYI... It looks like the Gradle team may have fixed the issue for Gradle 6.7 RC5 (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/14813).

Comment: FYI... We released Micronaut 2.1.1 today, which defaults to using Gradle 6.7 RC5.